# Jquery waypoint stickey issues

Tags: jquery, sticky, jquery-waypoints

Im trying to use jquery waypoints to produce some sticky navigation but I am running into issues.

On page

```
<script src="js/waypoints-sticky.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints-sticky.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    $(document).ready(function(){
         $(window).resize(function(){
             $('#mainsplash').css("height", ($(window).height() - 200) + "px");
         });
         $('#mainsplash').css("height", ($(window).height() - 200) + "px");
         $('.sticky1').waypoint('sticky', {
          offset: 0 // Apply "stuck" when element 30px from top
        });
    });


</script>
```

CSS

```
.stuck{position: fixed; top: 0;}
```

Issue1:  does not seem to work on divs?
If I apply a div with the class "sicky1" it does nothing.  However when I apply the class "stick1" to an H1 or A tag it works.  Is there no way to use this on a div?

Issue2:
Is there a way to apply a sticky to multiple elements and then have them sit under one another when the get to the top.

Basically what im trying to do is create an accordion affect. So lets say my page has 3 sections.

PRODUCT
- content
ABOUT
-CONTENT
CONTACT
-content.

When the user scrolls to the bottom, the three sections should be stuck to the top of the page under one another.

i.e. (these should be under one another next next to)
PRODCUT
ABOUT
CONTACT

- content -
  -footer-

Hope this makes sense.  Jquery is not my strong suit.

Answer (score 0):

never mind, I figured it out.  I wasn't sure why it wasn't working on the divs but it all of a sudden started working.  And by setting a margin-top in the css on the div and an offset in the jquery I was able to achieve the accordion affect.